# RESTful NoSQL search engine with server and spelling checker?

Tags: rest, nosql, search-engine

I'm looking for something like [ElasticSearch](http://elasticsearch.org) but with support of spell checking. Tired of running around with ASpell (plus thats slow).

It must be schema-free and document oriented, because I plan to use it **instead** of database.

Thank you.

Comment: why not use a phonetic analyzer?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936256/elastic-search-implement-did-you-mean/7193544#7193544

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider Apache Solr. Although Solr uses a schema, it also supports dynamic fields. Dynamic fields allow you to create new fields on the fly for the datatypes you choose to allow. For example, in Solr you can define a dynamic field like:

```
<dynamicField name="*_i"  type="integer"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

And then you can create integer fields dynamically with names like "somefield_i". Of course, you can use string types, date types, and many other kinds of types, such as text fields that support word stemming, synonym matching, and other search engine features.

Solr supports master-slave replication, spellcheck, and a host of other great features. It's document oriented and has a REST interface.

**Update:** Found a nice little blog post comparing indexing with Solr and Elastic search: http://dmurphy747.wordpress.com/2011/04/02/solr-vs-elasticsearch-deathmatch/ ... unfortunately doesn't dive into query performance.

Comment: I thought about solution based on Solr, but I would like to have native document support, w/o those hacks. Still have it as the option, but hope to get something better.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that although the use of dynamic fields may look hacky, there won't be any performance impact. Of course, Solr doesn't really provide the ability to nest fields inside of fields so you can't build the same kind of structures that you could in mongodb or something.