# Elastic Search - implement "Did you Mean"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

We are trying to use Elastic Search in a Rails app and would like any input/code example on the implementation of "did you mean" feature. Essentially, we want to provide the end user an option to search for an alternate query like in google.

Comment: I know "google it" answers are not great (hence this is a comment), but looking for "ruby spelling correction" would be a good start.

Comment: I did implement this, but in Asp.net MVC3. We used the algorithm described here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance. Try searching for "Fuzzy finding" on google.

Comment: Levenshtein distance: it should never be used for spell checking. In case anyone reads this, it is one of the worst spell checkers period.

Answer (score 9):

As of version 0.90.0.Beta1, ElasticSearch has a "term suggest" feature included, which is what you are looking for:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/term-suggest/

E.g. get from this query: "devloping distibutd saerch engies"
this result: "developing distributed search engines"

Answer (score 7):

Elasticsearch doesn't have it yet, it is opened as issue [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/911) basically it is waiting for the next Lucene [release](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/911#issuecomment-1199945).

I achieved a similar "did you mean" behaviour using the [phonetic analyzers](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/phonetic-tokenfilter.html), which worked for my use case, location names, that is not gonna work for all use cases....

a example mapping:- https://gist.github.com/1171014

so you can query using the REST api like this *(mispelled london)*:-

```
{
  "query": {
    "field": {
      "nameSounds": "lundon"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Detailed instructions on integrating the phonetic analyzer here: http://blog.jessitron.com/2012/04/configuring-soundex-in-elasticsearch.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use fuzzy search:

```
"fuzzy" : {
    "user" : {
        "value" :         "Jon",
        "boost" :         1.0,
        "fuzziness" :     3,
        "prefix_length" : 0,
        "max_expansions": 100
    }
}
```

Check this link for fuzzy : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html